# How do I use the --profile switch with aws-rb (part of the Ruby gem aws-sdk)?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services

I have several AWS keys defined via `[profile X]` within my `$HOME/.aws/config` file. When I try to use these with `aws-rb`, it seems as though this tool should work with them. Yet I'm not able to get it to do so. Specifically the `--profile` switch below:

```
$ aws-rb --help
Usage: aws-rb [options]
        --repl REPL                  specify the repl environment, pry or irb
    -e 'command'                     one line of script. Several -e's allowed.
    -l, --[no-]log                   log client requets, on by default
    -c, --[no-]color                 colorize request logging, on by default
        --profile PROFILE            Use a specific profile from your credential file.
    -d, --[no-]debug                 log HTTP wire traces, off by default
    -Idirectory                      specify $LOAD_PATH directory (may be used more than once)
    -rlibrary                        require the library
    -v, --verbose                    enable client logging and HTTP wire tracing
    -q, --quiet                      disable client logging and HTTP wire tracing
    -h, --help
```

#### Example

The profile I'd like to use:

```
$ grep stag ~/.aws/config 
[profile stag]
```

When I attempt to get a list of the S3 bucket names:

```
$ aws-rb -vd --profile stag
[1]pry(AWS)> s3.buckets.map(&:name)
AWS::Errors::MissingCredentialsError: 
Missing Credentials.
```

If I use `aws` I can see that my credentials work fine from the AWS config file:

```
$ AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=stag /usr/bin/aws s3 ls
2014-03-01 14:36:38 bucket1
2013-07-01 12:01:29 bucket2
```

#### References

- [Using the AWS SDK for Ruby from Your REPL](http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx37CB1ZX8AGBQ5/Using-the-AWS-SDK-for-Ruby-from-Your-REPL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS various AWS SDKs (including Ruby) load shared credentials from `~/.aws/credentials`, but not from `~/.aws/config`. The `~/.aws/config` file is currently only consumed by the AWS CLI.  The shared credentials file is only for secrets and should look like:

```
[stag]
aws_access_key_id=AKID
aws_secret_access_key=SECRET
```

Notice there is no "profile" prefix in the ini file section for each profile.